# First loop through columns and then loop through through rows

Tags: loops, sas, minimization, do-loops

I want to loop first through columns and then through rows.

```
    data test ;
    input cat $ cat3 cat4 cat5 cat6 cat7 cat8 num_rat ;
    cards;
          cat3 0 -1.78 -2.68 -3.06 -3.4 -3.83 1885
          cat4 0 2.12 -2.15 -2.63 -2.94 -3.34 3151
          cat5 0 2.45 1.16 -1.39 -1.99 -2.54 246
          cat6 0 2.48 1.92 1.19 -1.13 -2.39 80
          cat7 0 2.68 2.32 1.82 1.52 -1.56 89
    ;
    run;


DATA TEST1;
SET test;
Array Cat_C(6) cat3-cat8;
Array Cat_g(5) catg3-catg7;
do i= 1to 5;
cat_g(i)= num_rat * ((((CDF('Normal', Cat_C(i+1))-CDF('NORMAL',Cat_C(i))-
((CDF('NORMAL', ((Cat_C(i+1) - (sqrt(&rho)*&z))/sqrt(1-&rho))))-(CDF 
('NORMAL', ((Cat_C(i) - (sqrt(&rho)*&z))/sqrt(1-&rho))))))**2))/
(((CDF('NORMAL', ((Cat_C(i+1) - (sqrt(&rho)*&z))/sqrt(1-&rho))))-(CDF 
('NORMAL', ((Cat_C(i) - (sqrt(&rho)*&z))/sqrt(1-&rho)))))*(1- /**/((CDF('NORMAL', ((Cat_C(i+1) - (sqrt(&rho)*&z))/sqrt(1-&rho))))-(CDF 
('NORMAL', ((Cat_C(i) - (sqrt(&rho)*&z))/sqrt(1-&rho))))))));
    end;
    run;
```

I need to sum for cat3 (row) by first subtraction (0 + -1.78)*1885 + (-1.78 + -2.68)*1885 + (-2.68 + -3.06)*1885 + (-3.06 + -3.4)*1885 + (-3.4 + -3.83)*1885

and then calculate for all the rows (cat4, cat5, cat6, cat7) and then sum all the rows together and minimize them like (min(sum_rows).

The minimization equation can be found at this paper:
https://www.z-riskengine.com/media/1032/a-one-parameter-representation-of-credit-risk-and-transition-matrices.pdf

where x(g+1) is the movement from cat3 to cat4. and rho needs to be any fixed number (say 0.8) and z needs to be minimized using any initial number (say 0.89).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data you might try working with a 2D array.

```
data test ;
  input cat $ cat3 cat4 cat5 cat6 cat7 cat8 num_rat ;
  cards;
cat3 0 -1.78 -2.68 -3.06 -3.4  -3.83 1885
cat4 0  2.12 -2.15 -2.63 -2.94 -3.34 3151
cat5 0  2.45  1.16 -1.39 -1.99 -2.54 246
cat6 0  2.48  1.92  1.19 -1.13 -2.39 80
cat7 0  2.68  2.32  1.82  1.52 -1.56 89
  ;

data _null_;

  array X (3:7,3:9);  * column index 9 is num_rat;

  * load 2D array;
  do row = 3 to 7;
    set test;
    array cols cat3-cat8 num_rat;
    do col = 3 to 9;
      X(row,col) = cols(col-2);
    end;
  end;

  do index1 = 3 to 7;
    do index2 = 3 to 9;
      putlog @(8*(index2-3)+1) X(index1,index2) @;
    end;
    putlog;
  end;
run;
```

Other alternatives is to do row-wise computations in `DATA Step` and column-wise computations with `Proc MEANS`

You can also look into `Proc IML`, `SAS/OR`, `Proc FCMP` and the `SOLVE` function, or `Proc DS22` and it's matrix functions.